# How to find the mime type of a file in python?

Tags: python, mime

Let's say you want to save a bunch of files somewhere, for instance in BLOBs. Let's say you want to dish these files out via a web page and have the client automatically open the correct application/viewer.

Assumption: The browser figures out which application/viewer to use by the mime-type (content-type?) header in the HTTP response.

Based on that assumption, in addition to the bytes of the file, you also want to save the MIME type.

How would you find the MIME type of a file? I'm currently on a Mac, but this should also work on Windows.

Does the browser add this information when posting the file to the web page?

Is there a neat python library for finding this information? A WebService or (even better) a downloadable database?

Comment: Hey there to all newcomers. Just a quick overview over this topic, because the answers get harder to read with each new one:
The `mimetypes` python standard library module uses the *file extension* only.
Any of the several `libmagic` integrations use the *file contents*.
For details read on below ;-)

Answer (score 308, accepted):

The python-magic method suggested by [toivotuo](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2133843/5337834) is outdated. [Python-magic's](http://github.com/ahupp/python-magic) current trunk is at Github and based on the readme there, finding the MIME-type, is done like this.

```
# For MIME types
import magic
mime = magic.Magic(mime=True)
mime.from_file("testdata/test.pdf") # 'application/pdf'
```

Comment: thanks for the comment! please note, that "above" is a difficult concept in stackoverflow, since the ordering is grouped by votes and ordered randomly inside the groups. I am guessing you refer to @toivotuo's answer.

Comment: Yeh, I didn\t have enough "points" to create comments at the time of writing this reply. But I probably should have written it as a comment, so that the @toivotuo could have edited his question.

Comment: rpm -qf /usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/magic.py -i 
    URL         : http://www.darwinsys.com/file/
    Summary     : Python bindings for the libmagic API


    rpm -qf /usr/bin/file -i
    Name        : file
    URL         : http://www.darwinsys.com/file/


python-magic from http://www.darwinsys.com/file/ and which comes with Linux Fedora works like @toivotuo's said. And seems more main stream.

Comment: Since the magic library is not a standard python lib, this is very clumsy :-( Isn't there some way how to use unix `file` command directly? Unfortunately `s = os.system("file -b --mime-type /home/me/myfile.bz2")` doesn't write the MIME into `s`, but only prints it to stdout :-(

Comment: Beware that the debian/ubuntu package called python-magic is different to the pip package of the same name.  Both are `import magic` but have incompatible contents.  See http://stackoverflow.com/a/16203777/3189 for more.

Comment: The `magic` module comes from [`filemagic` on pypi](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/filemagic)

Comment: Check my answer in the context of no file extension or false file extension, Python 3.X and web application stackoverflow.com/a/39356849/1209842

Comment: As I commented on toivotuo’s answer, it is not outdated! You are talking about a different library. Can you please remove or replace that statement in your answer? It currently makes finding the best solution really difficult.

Comment: js and css are just "text/plain" with this!

Comment: As saif by @ManojAcharya, this will not give useful results when applying it to most web-related files. Basically everything will be text/plain, except to XML file which will either be text/html or text/xml (!), depending on the library’s mood. When you need to get results for web files, you should use the mimetypes module (see the answers by dave-webb, oetzi and others below).

Answer (score 127):

The [mimetypes module](https://docs.python.org/library/mimetypes.html) in the standard library will determine/guess the MIME type from a file extension.

If users are uploading files the HTTP post will contain the MIME type of the file alongside the data.  For example, Django makes this data available as an attribute of the [UploadedFile](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/http/file-uploads/#uploadedfile-objects) object.

Comment: If the files are stored in BLOBs, as specified in the question, you may not know the file extension.

Comment: Also remember to sanitize the files when/if outputting them to other users: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1745743/validating-uploaded-files-in-django

Comment: File extensions are not a reliable way to determine mime type.

Comment: Echoing some of the comments above, a better solution is in [Simon's answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/2753385/874188).

Comment: `import mimetypes`

`mimetypes.MimeTypes().guess_type(filename)[0]`

Comment: in python 3.6 this works: `mimetypes.guess_type(path_file_to_upload)[1] `

Comment: While @cerin is right that file extensions are not reliable, I've just discovered that the accuracy of `python-magic` (as suggested in the top answer) to be even lower, as confirmed by https://github.com/s3tools/s3cmd/issues/198. So, `mimetypes` seems a better candidate for me.

Comment: While @Cerin is basically right, getting `text/plain` for CSS, JavaScript etc. and `text/xml` (as ASCII) for XML containing a lot of non-ASCII characters is completely useless and even potentially harmful. Hence, for now, mimetypes is the way to go.

Comment: @JinSnow Thanks for the syntax tip. I would default to checking part [0] -- the type, not the encoding. The response for me usually looked like `("application/json", None)`.

Comment: As of Python 3.8 `mimetypes.guess_type` now accepts a `Path`-like object. So it's compatible with Python's pathlib module. issue: https://bugs.python.org/issue34926

Answer (score 59):

This seems to be very easy

```
>>> from mimetypes import MimeTypes
>>> import urllib 
>>> mime = MimeTypes()
>>> url = urllib.pathname2url('Upload.xml')
>>> mime_type = mime.guess_type(url)
>>> print mime_type
('application/xml', None)
```

Please refer [Old Post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14412233/1182058)

**Update** - In python 3+ version, it's more convenient now:

```
import mimetypes
print(mimetypes.guess_type("sample.html"))
```

Comment: I don't think the urllib is required in your example.

Comment: for Python 3.X replace import urllib with from urllib import request. And then use "request" instead of urllib

Comment: Works for python 2.7 also

Comment: @oetzi's [solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57941308/2223706) uses this module, but is more simple.

Answer (score 56):

More reliable way than to use the mimetypes library would be to use the python-magic package.

```
import magic
m = magic.open(magic.MAGIC_MIME)
m.load()
m.file("/tmp/document.pdf")
```

This would be equivalent to using file(1).

On Django one could also make sure that the MIME type matches that of UploadedFile.content_type.

Comment: See Simon Zimmermann's post for an updated use of python-magic

Comment: @DarenThomas: As mentioned in mammadori’s answer, this answer is *not* outdated and distinct from Simon Zimmermann’s solution. If you have the file utility installed, you can probably use this solution. It works for me with file-5.32. On gentoo you also have to have the python USE-flag enabled for the file package.

Answer (score 39):

13 year later...
Most of the answers on this page for python 3 were either outdated or incomplete.
To get the mime type of a file I use:

```
import mimetypes

mt = mimetypes.guess_type("https://www.w3.org/WAI/ER/tests/xhtml/testfiles/resources/pdf/dummy.pdf")
if mt:
    print("Mime Type:", mt[0])
else:
    print("Cannot determine Mime Type")

# Mime Type: application/pdf
```

---

[Live Demo](https://trinket.io/python3/1485835cd1)

---

From [Python docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/mimetypes.html#mimetypes.guess_type):

`mimetypes.guess_type`(*url*, *strict=True*)

Guess the type of a file based on its filename, path or URL, given by *url*. URL can be a string or a [path-like object](https://docs.python.org/3/glossary.html#term-path-like-object).

The return value is a tuple `(type, encoding)` where *type* is `None` if the type can’t be guessed (missing or unknown suffix) or a string of the form `'type/subtype'`, usable for a MIME *content-type* header.

*encoding* is `None` for no encoding or the name of the program used to encode (e.g. **compress** or **gzip**). The encoding is suitable for use as a *Content-Encoding* header, **not** as a *Content-Transfer-Encoding* header. The mappings are table driven. Encoding suffixes are case sensitive; type suffixes are first tried case sensitively, then case insensitively.

The optional *strict* argument is a flag specifying whether the list of known MIME types is limited to only the official types [registered with IANA](https://www.iana.org/assignments/media-types/media-types.xhtml). When *strict* is `True` (the default), only the IANA types are supported; when *strict* is `False`, some additional non-standard but commonly used MIME types are also recognized.

Changed in version 3.8: Added support for url being a [path-like object](https://docs.python.org/3/glossary.html#term-path-like-object).

Comment: if file path has no extension,then mime can not get the right result.

Comment: it is a great option, but not only does it require an extension, but also things like 'image/webp' are still not being detected.

Answer (score 18):

## Python bindings to libmagic

All the different answers on this topic are very confusing, so I’m hoping to give a bit more clarity with this overview of the different bindings of libmagic. Previously mammadori gave a [short answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2753385/1534459) listing the available option.

### libmagic

- module name: `magic`
- pypi: [file-magic](https://pypi.org/project/file-magic/)
- source: https://github.com/file/file/tree/master/python

When determining a files mime-type, the tool of choice is simply called `file` and its back-end is called `libmagic`. (See the [Project home page](http://www.darwinsys.com/file/).) The project is developed in a private cvs-repository, but there is a [read-only git mirror on github](https://github.com/file/file).

Now this tool, which you will need if you want to use any of the libmagic bindings with python, already comes with its own python bindings called [`file-magic`](https://pypi.org/project/file-magic/). There is not much dedicated documentation for them, but you can always have a look at the man page of the c-library: [`man libmagic`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/libmagic.3.html). The basic usage is described in the [readme file](https://github.com/file/file/tree/master/python):

```
import magic

detected = magic.detect_from_filename('magic.py')
print 'Detected MIME type: {}'.format(detected.mime_type)
print 'Detected encoding: {}'.format(detected.encoding)
print 'Detected file type name: {}'.format(detected.name)
```

Apart from this, you can also use the library by creating a `Magic` object using `magic.open(flags)` as shown in the [example file](https://github.com/file/file/tree/master/python/example.py).

Both [toivotuo](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2133843/1534459) and ewr2san use these `file-magic` bindings included in the `file` tool. They mistakenly assume, they are using the `python-magic` package. *This seems to indicate, that if both `file` and `python-magic` are installed, the python module `magic` refers to the former one.*

### python-magic

- module name: `magic`
- pypi: [python-magic](https://pypi.org/project/python-magic/)
- source: https://github.com/ahupp/python-magic

This is the library that Simon Zimmermann talks about in [his answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2753385/1534459) and which is also employed by [Claude COULOMBE](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2753385/1534459) as well as [Gringo Suave](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46758932/1534459).

### filemagic

- module name: `magic`
- pypi: [filemagic](https://pypi.org/project/filemagic/)
- source: https://github.com/aliles/filemagic

**Note**: This project was last updated in 2013!

Due to being based on the same c-api, this library has some similarity with `file-magic` included in `libmagic`. It is only mentioned by [mammadori](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2753385/1534459) and no other answer employs it.

Answer (score 15):

**2017 Update**

No need to go to github, it is on PyPi under a different name:

```
pip3 install --user python-magic
# or:
sudo apt install python3-magic  # Ubuntu distro package
```

The code can be simplified as well:

```
>>> import magic

>>> magic.from_file('/tmp/img_3304.jpg', mime=True)
'image/jpeg'
```

Comment: can you do same for js or css file ?

Comment: Sure, why not??

Answer (score 11):

There are 3 different libraries that wraps libmagic.

2 of them are available on pypi (so pip install will work):

- filemagic
- python-magic

And another, similar to python-magic is available directly in the latest libmagic sources, and it is the one you probably have in your linux distribution.

In Debian the package python-magic is about this one and it is used as toivotuo said and it is not obsoleted as Simon Zimmermann said (IMHO).

It seems to me another take (by the original author of libmagic).

Too bad is not available directly on pypi.

Comment: I added a repo for convenience: https://github.com/mammadori/magic-python

that way you can:


`pip install -e git://github.com/mammadori/magic-python.git#egg=Magic_file_extensions`

Answer (score 10):

in python 2.6:

```
import shlex
import subprocess
mime = subprocess.Popen("/usr/bin/file --mime " + shlex.quote(PATH), shell=True, \
    stdout=subprocess.PIPE).communicate()[0]
```

Comment: This is unnecessary, since the `file` command is basically just a wrapper around libmagic. You may as well just use the python binding (python-magic), as in Simon's answer.

Comment: That depends on the operating system. On Mac OS X, for example, you have "file" but not libmagic in the normal environment.

Comment: this looks unsafe to me, PATH should be escaped. idk what the Python equivalent is, but php devs would use `Popen("/usr/bin/file --mime ".escapeshellarg(PATH));`  - for example your code would fail on files containing newlines or quotes, probably also $dollarsign, but it would also protect you against hackers doing `PATH='; rm -rfv /` and such shell injection

Answer (score 8):

python 3 ref: https://docs.python.org/3.2/library/mimetypes.html

> mimetypes.guess_type(url, strict=True) Guess the type of a file based
>   on its filename or URL, given by url. The return value is a tuple
>   (type, encoding) where type is None if the type can’t be guessed
>   (missing or unknown suffix) or a string of the form 'type/subtype',
>   usable for a MIME content-type header.
>
> encoding is None for no encoding or the name of the program used to
>   encode (e.g. compress or gzip). The encoding is suitable for use as a
>   Content-Encoding header, not as a Content-Transfer-Encoding header.
>   The mappings are table driven. Encoding suffixes are case sensitive;
>   type suffixes are first tried case sensitively, then case
>   insensitively.
>
> The optional strict argument is a flag specifying whether the list of
>   known MIME types is limited to only the official types registered with
>   IANA. When strict is True (the default), only the IANA types are
>   supported; when strict is False, some additional non-standard but
>   commonly used MIME types are also recognized.

```
import mimetypes
print(mimetypes.guess_type("sample.html"))
```

Answer (score 7):

You didn't state what web server you were using, but Apache has a nice little module called [Mime Magic](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/1.3/mod/mod_mime_magic.html) which it uses to determine the type of a file when told to do so.  It reads some of the file's content and tries to figure out what type it is based on the characters found.  And as [Dave Webb Mentioned](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43580/how-to-find-the-mime-type-of-a-file-in-python#43588) the [MimeTypes Module](http://docs.python.org/lib/module-mimetypes.html) under python will work, provided an extension is handy.

Alternatively, if you are sitting on a UNIX box you can use `sys.popen('file -i ' + fileName, mode='r')` to grab the MIME type.  Windows should have an equivalent command, but I'm unsure as to what it is.

Comment: Nowdays you can just do subprocess.check_output(['file', '-b', '--mime', filename])

Comment: There is really no reason to resort to using an external tool when python-magic does the equivalent thing, all wrapped and cozy.

Answer (score 7):

@toivotuo 's method worked best and most reliably for me under python3.  My goal was to identify gzipped files which do not have a reliable .gz extension. I installed python3-magic.

```
import magic

filename = "./datasets/test"

def file_mime_type(filename):
    m = magic.open(magic.MAGIC_MIME)
    m.load()
    return(m.file(filename))

print(file_mime_type(filename))
```

for a gzipped file it returns:
application/gzip; charset=binary

for an unzipped txt file (iostat data):
text/plain; charset=us-ascii

for a tar file:
application/x-tar; charset=binary

for a bz2 file: 
application/x-bzip2; charset=binary

and last but not least for me a .zip file: 
application/zip; charset=binary

Answer (score 6):

In Python 3.x and webapp with url to the file which couldn't have an extension or a fake extension. You should install python-magic, using

```
pip3 install python-magic
```

For Mac OS X, you should also install libmagic using

```
brew install libmagic
```

Code snippet

```
import urllib
import magic
from urllib.request import urlopen

url = "http://...url to the file ..."
request = urllib.request.Request(url)
response = urlopen(request)
mime_type = magic.from_buffer(response.readline())
print(mime_type)
```

alternatively you could put a size into the read

```
import urllib
import magic
from urllib.request import urlopen

url = "http://...url to the file ..."
request = urllib.request.Request(url)
response = urlopen(request)
mime_type = magic.from_buffer(response.read(128))
print(mime_type)
```

Comment: Will it be load whole file?

Comment: No, it's a stream, so normally just few bytes.

Comment: I've edited by response.readline() or  response.read(128) Thank you!

Answer (score 5):

I try mimetypes library first. If it's not working, I use python-magic libary instead.

```
import mimetypes
def guess_type(filename, buffer=None):
mimetype, encoding = mimetypes.guess_type(filename)
if mimetype is None:
    try:
        import magic
        if buffer:
            mimetype = magic.from_buffer(buffer, mime=True)
        else:
            mimetype = magic.from_file(filename, mime=True)
    except ImportError:
        pass
return mimetype
```

Answer (score 2):

The mimetypes module just recognise an file type based on file extension. If you will try to recover a file type of a file without extension, the mimetypes will not works.

Comment: I don't think that's true. The MIME type is about how to tell others about a data format, not about how to find out the data format yourself. If you use a tool that guesses the format only based on the extension and prints out MIME types then you can't use that tool if there are no file extensions. But other ways to guess the format are possible as well, e.g., by checking with a parser.

Answer (score 2):

I'm surprised that nobody has mentioned it but [Pygments](https://pypi.org/project/Pygments) is able to make an educated guess about the mime-type of, particularly, text documents.

Pygments is actually a Python syntax highlighting library but is has a method that will make an educated guess about which of 500 supported document types your document is.
i.e. c++ vs C# vs Python vs etc

```py
import inspect

def _test(text: str):
    from pygments.lexers import guess_lexer
    lexer = guess_lexer(text)
    mimetype = lexer.mimetypes[0] if lexer.mimetypes else None
    print(mimetype)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    # Set the text to the actual defintion of _test(...) above
    text = inspect.getsource(_test)
    print('Text:')
    print(text)
    print()
    print('Result:')
    _test(text)
```

Output:

```
Text:
def _test(text: str):
    from pygments.lexers import guess_lexer
    lexer = guess_lexer(text)
    mimetype = lexer.mimetypes[0] if lexer.mimetypes else None
    print(mimetype)


Result:
text/x-python
```

Now, it's not perfect, but if you need to be able to tell which of 500 document formats are being used, this is pretty darn useful.

Answer (score 1):

I 've tried a lot of examples but with Django [mutagen](http://mutagen.readthedocs.io) plays nicely.

Example checking if files is `mp3`

```
from mutagen.mp3 import MP3, HeaderNotFoundError  

try:
    audio = MP3(file)
except HeaderNotFoundError:
    raise ValidationError('This file should be mp3')
```

The downside is that your ability to check file types is limited, but it's a great way if you want not only check for file type but also to access additional information.

Answer (score 1):

For byte Array type data you can use 
magic.from_buffer(_byte_array,mime=True)

Answer (score 0):

I have had trouble getting any of the `magic` implementation modules to work under MSYS2 with Python 3. What I settled on was calling the `file` executable & falling back to the `mimetypes` module.

```
import mimetypes
import os
import subprocess

def getMimeType(filepath):
  mime_type = None
  # replace '<system_root>/usr/bin/file.exe' with path to 'file' executuble for your system
  if os.path.isfile(filepath) and os.path.isfile("<system_root>/usr/bin/file.exe"):
    res = subprocess.run(["/usr/bin/file", "--mime-type", "--brief", filepath], stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
    if res.stdout:
      mime_type = res.stdout.decode("utf-8")
  if not mime_type:
    # fallback to guessing by filename extension
    mime_type = mimetypes.guess_type(filepath)[0]
  return mime_type
```

Note that it would be good to have a function to search PATH for the 'file' executable instead of hardcoding it in.

You could also use this as a fallback if a usable `magic` module isn't found.

```
__have_magic = False
try:
  import magic
  __have_magic = True
except ModuleNotFoundError:
  pass

...

def getMimeType(filepath):
  mime_type = None
  if __have_magic and os.path.isfile(filepath):
    mime_type = magic.from_file(filepath, mime=True)
  if not mime_type:
    # fallback to 'file' call
    ...
```