# Filetype information

Tags: python

I'm in the process of writing a python script, and I want to find out information about a file, such as for example a mime-type (or any useful depiction of what a file contains).

I've heard about python-magic, but I'm really looking for *the* solution that will allow me to find this information, without requiring the installation of additional packages.

Am I stuck to maintaining a list of file extensions, or does python have something in the standard library? I was not able to find it in the docs.

Comment: Duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43580/how-to-find-the-mime-type-of-a-file-in-python

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I am not sure if you want to infer something from file content but if you want to know mime type from file extension mimetypes module will be sufficient

```
>>> import mimetypes
>>> mimetypes.init()
>>> mimetypes.knownfiles
['/etc/mime.types', '/etc/httpd/mime.types', ... ]
>>> mimetypes.suffix_map['.tgz']
'.tar.gz'
>>> mimetypes.encodings_map['.gz']
'gzip'
>>> mimetypes.types_map['.tgz']
'application/x-tar-gz'
```

http://docs.python.org/library/mimetypes.html

Answer (score 1):

The standard library has support for [mapping filenames to mimetypes](http://docs.python.org/library/mimetypes.html#module-mimetypes).

Your question also sounds like you are interested in other information besides mimetype.  The [stat](http://docs.python.org/library/stat.html) module will also give you information about size, owner, time of last modification, etc. but otherwise the most common filesystems (Windows NTFS/FAT, Linux Ext 2/3, Mac OS X) do not store any metadata or "other information" about files.  That's why we need to use extensions to find the mimetype for example.