# How may i get the idea video is flash or not?

Tags: flash, video

It's general question nothing related with code.
I want to know that video which i am playing is flash video or not.
Are there any way we can get idea about it? Can we get idea from source code ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Video itself is never "FLASH" (unless you are talking about **SWF encoding**). What's flash is the player you use for streaming.

If the [tag](http://kb2.adobe.com/cps/415/tn_4150.html) embedding the video contains a `type` attribute like `application/x-shockwave-flash` or similar, then it's a flash player, or the filename is something ending in **SWF** (it means video encoded in **SWF** format), then is a video for playing on a flash player.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this with obtaining the mime-type [How to find the mime type of a file in python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43580/how-to-find-the-mime-type-of-a-file-in-python)