# How to Email a Django FileField as an Attachment?

Tags: django, email-attachments, filefield

I need to send a `models.FileField` as an email attachment using Django. I've seen snippets that show how to do this with the raw `request.FILES` data (which still contains the Content-Type), but have not been able to find anything that shows how to do it once you've already saved the file in a `models.FileField`. The content type seems to be inaccessible from the `models.FileField`.

Can someone give me an example of how this would work? I'm beginning to think that I might have to store the Content-Type in the model when I save the file.

Thanks!

Comment: Could you provide the solution you found as an answer? I'd like to see the snippet too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would just not supply a content type and let the recipient's email client work it out. Unless it will be something unusual it shouldn't be a problem.

[RFC2616](http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec7.html#sec7.2.1) states:

> If and only if the media type is not
>   given by a Content-Type field, the
>   recipient MAY attempt to guess the
>   media type via inspection of its
>   content and/or the name extension(s)
>   of the URI used to identify the
>   resource.

**but**... 
If you want to specify it then storing the content type on upload is a very good idea. It should be noted that django's own docs say to [verify the data from users](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/http/file-uploads/?from=olddocs#django.core.files.uploadedfile.UploadedFile.content_type)

If you are on a *unix OS you could try to guess/inspect it:

```
import subprocess
subprocess.check_output(['file', '-b', '--mime', filename])
```

*(from [How to find the mime type of a file in python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43580/how-to-find-the-mime-type-of-a-file-in-python/43616#43616) )*

Comment: Thanks! I'll give this a go and report back!

Answer (score 19):

Attaching a models.FileField file to an email message is nice and simple in Django:

```
from django.core.mail import EmailMultiAlternatives
kwargs = dict(
    to=to,
    from_email=from_addr,
    subject=subject,
    body=text_content,
    alternatives=((html_content, 'text/html'),)
)
message = EmailMultiAlternatives(**kwargs)
message.attach_file(model_instance.filefield.path)
message.send()
```

Answer (score 8):

I am using [django-storages](https://django-storages.readthedocs.io/en/latest/) and so `.path` raises

```
NotImplementedError: This backend doesn't support absolute paths.
```

To avoid this, I simply open the file, read it, guess the mimetype and close it later, but having to use `.attach` instead of `.attach_file` magic.

```
from mimetypes import guess_type
from os.path import basename


f = model.filefield
f.open()
# msg.attach(filename, content, mimetype)
msg.attach(basename(f.name), f.read(), guess_type(f.name)[0])
f.close()
```

Comment: It seems odd that the django mail module doesn't provide a better interface to the storage backend. This is the safest answer to work with multiple backends and is the one you need if you aren't using a filesystem backend. The question asked is how to email a django filefield as an attachment, but the answers that depend on the file being on a filesystem storage are really just answering the question for that filesystem storage backend configuration.

Answer (score 6):

Another approach:

```
from django.core.mail.message import EmailMessage

msg = EmailMessage(subject=my_subject, body=my_email_body, 
      from_email=settings.DEFAULT_FROM_EMAIL, to=[to_addressed])
msg.attach_file(self.my_filefield.path) # self.my_filefield.file for Django < 1.7
msg.send(fail_silently=not(settings.DEBUG))
```

Comment: I had to use `msg.attach_file(self.my_filefield.path)` with Django 1.7.1