# Obtaining file type in django template

Tags: django, django-templates, django-file-upload

I need to get the file type of the uploaded file in django template.
I have written a templatetag for getting file name but I need file type also.

I might be able to get the content-type of the file but I couldn't find it while debugging.

**doc_list.html**

```
{{ d.file|filename }}
{{ d.file|filetype }}
```

**templatetags/helper.py**

```
register = template.Library()

@register.filter
def filename(value):
    return os.path.basename(value.file.name)

@register.filter
def filetype(value):
    return ???
```

Comment: What exactly do you mean by "file type"? MIME type?

Comment: Yes, I need MIME type. Sorry for confusion

Comment: Check http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43580/how-to-find-the-mime-type-of-a-file-in-python

Answer (score 2):

[USE mimetypes module](http://docs.python.org/library/mimetypes.html#mimetypes.guess_type)

```
import mimetypes    

>>> mimetypes.guess_type('a.py',strict = True)
('text/x-python', None)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
mime = magic.Magic(mime=True)
mime.from_file("testdata/test.pdf")
```

returns:

```
'application/pdf'
```