# Detect file type from the file contents, not the file name

Tags: python

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to find the mime type of a file in python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43580/how-to-find-the-mime-type-of-a-file-in-python)

I want to detect the type of a file, but I don't want to look at the extension because it may be incorrect. The `mimetypes` module is filename based.

Is there a standard way to peek inside the file?

Comment: Why is it not good? Provide evidence

Comment: I don't want to use mimetypes module because this module look only for file path. For example name of file test.pdf but this is .doc file with fake name.

Comment: NOT A DUPLICATE QUESTION -- the referenced answer is looking at file name not file content

Comment: Check my answer in the context of no file extension or false file extension, Python 3.X and web application http://stackoverflow.com/a/39356849/1209842

Answer (score 7):

Try installing the [python-magic](http://pypi.python.org/pypi/python-magic/) module.

```
 >>> mime = magic.Magic(mime=True)
 >>> mime.from_file("testdata/abc.pdf")
'application/pdf'
```

Comment: +1 good answer, but I had to hunt for it and the documentation is um... brief. It probably only works on unixes too, but I'm not sure.

Comment: This is good module, but I want to use only standart library.

Comment: Check my answer in the context of no file extension or false file extension, Python 3.X and web application http://stackoverflow.com/a/39356849/1209842