# Get the mimetype of a file with Python

Tags: python

I want determine mimetype of an xml file , but I am getting error about some instance as first argument. I am new to python please help. Below is the code I am using and the error it throws.

```
from mimetypes import MimeTypes
import urllib 
FILENAME = 'Upload.xml'
url = urllib.pathname2url(FILENAME)
type = MimeTypes.guess_type(url)
print type

**ERROR :** Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/home/navi/Desktop/quicksort.py", line 20, in <module>
type = MimeTypes.guess_type(url)
TypeError: unbound method guess_type() must be called with MimeTypes instance as first argument (got str instance instead)
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to find the mime type of a file in python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43580/how-to-find-the-mime-type-of-a-file-in-python)

Answer (score 23):

The error says that you have to initialize the `MimeTypes` class:

```
>>> from mimetypes import MimeTypes
>>> import urllib 
>>> 
>>> mime = MimeTypes()
>>> url = urllib.pathname2url('Upload.xml')
>>> mime_type = mime.guess_type(url)
>>> 
>>> print mime_type
('application/xml', None)
```

Although you could skip this and use `mimetypes.guess_type` directly:

```
>>> import urllib, mimetypes
>>> 
>>> url = urllib.pathname2url('Upload.xml')
>>> print mimetypes.guess_type(url)
('application/xml', None)
```

Comment: A more direct approach is to use `mimetypes.guess_type` directly rather than via a `MimeTypes` instance.

Comment: @bdash  i tried same thing in my code didnt work , please check the code pasted inn question

Comment: @devileye Your code doesn't do what I suggested. Take a look at the second part of this answer.

Comment: in python 3.6: `mimetypes.guess_type(path_file_to_upload)[1]`

Comment: @JinSnow Should it be `mimetypes.guess_type(path_file_to_upload)[0]`?

Comment: @ytu Sorry, I don't remember. To check it, just print it (with 0 and 1)