# How can i get a file extension from a filetype?

Tags: python, file

I have a list of filenames as follows

```
files = [
    '/dl/files/4j55eeer_wq3wxxpiqm.jpg',
    '/home/Desktop/hjsd03wnsbdr9rk3k',
    'kd0dje7cmidj0xks03nd8nd8a3',
    ...
]
```

The problem is most of the files do not have an extension in the filenames, what would be the best way to get file extension of these files ?

I don't know if this is even possible because python would treat all files as `buffer` or `string` objects that do not have any `filetype` associated with them.

can this be done at all ?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14412211/get-mimetype-of-file-python but that will give you type not the extension though

Comment: Should this be portable? UNIX's `file` is usually really good at finding the file types...

Comment: @Bakuriu: `file` uses `libmagic`, and that is cross-platform. See the `python-magic` library John Zwinck links to below.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Once you use `magic` to get the MIME type, you can use [`mimetypes.guess_extension()`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/mimetypes.html#mimetypes.guess_extension) to get the extension for it.

Comment: why does `guess_extension` return `*.jpe` for mimetype `image/jpeg`, does it simply use split on '/' and then returns the first 3 characters of the second element prefixed with a `.` ??

Comment: @Amyth: It does have "guess" in the name, so a bit of leeway is expected.

Comment: Hmm, get it, but I guess, `return '.' + mime.split('/')[1]` would return more accurate results then ?

Comment: No, because `text/plain` should not have `.pla` as an extension.

Comment: @Amyth: the reason it returns `.jpe` is because `*.jpe` is one of many valid extensions for a mimetype of `image/jpeg`. If you use [mimetypes.guess_all_extensions()](https://docs.python.org/2/library/mimetypes.html#mimetypes.guess_all_extensions) instead, you'll see the entire list of possibilities. It seems like [mimetypes.guess_extension()](http://docs.python.org/2/library/mimetypes.html#mimetypes.guess_extension) just takes the first element of this list. This is also the reason guessing the mimetype of `text/plain` returns `.h` when `.txt` is the obvious choice.

Answer (score 3):

It can be done if you have an oracle that determines file types from their content.  Happily at least one such oracle is already implemented in Python: https://github.com/ahupp/python-magic

Answer (score 1):

The below code worked for me :

```
import filetype

fileinfo = filetype.guess(mock.jpg) #the argument can be buffer/file
detectedExt = fileinfo.extension
detectedmime = fileinfo.mime
```

[filetype package documentation](https://pypi.org/project/filetype/)