# Get system file type names python

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-os

Is there any way to retrieve a file type name in Python using the OS module?

An example made up command:

```
>>> os.file_type('txt')
```

Would return:

```
'Text Document'
```

Any help would be appreciated :)

Oscar.

Comment: Check this out: https://github.com/ahupp/python-magic

Comment: 'using the OS module'

Comment: Why would that kind of thing be in the `os` module?

Comment: mimetype module is related to such things, not os.

Comment: Found a thread on this topic: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16872139/how-can-i-get-a-file-extension-from-a-filetype. Old, but hopefully helpful

Answer (score 0):

For getting file type you need to check the extension of the file

I think this can help.

```
import os

if os.path.splitext(file)[1] == ".txt":
    pritn 'Text Document'
```

For os related task you can look over this doc.

https://github.com/Projesh07/Python-basic/blob/master/python_os_module/python_os_module.py