# Django development server not returning JSON responses

Tags: javascript, json, django, django-dev-server

Or rather, it's returning them as text, which is really odd. So I have this line of code in my javascript to test this that's

```
 $.get('/static/js/categories.json', function(response){ console.log(response); });
```

I can verify that the actual location of the resource exists because the status code is 200, and I see responseText with the contents in the Chrome console window. Now the issue is that...

When I run it from the **dev server** locally there's only *responseText*

When I run it on **the actual site**, in the console, it returns *responseJSON* and *responseText*.

Does anyone know why this is the case? Essentially, it's not returning a javascript object

So the actual server runs apache. Is it possible that for some reason the Django dev server is setting the MIME types of responses incorrectly?

---

**Apparent fix**

Well it seems like this was the same problem encountered in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18271257/resource-interpreted-as-font-but-transferred-with-mime-type-font-woff-django) question. It was fixed by adding

```
if DEBUG:
    import mimetypes
    mimetypes.add_type("application/json", ".json", True)
```

In **settings.py**, but that doesn't answer the bigger question of WHY the development server can't correctly set the MIME type for some types of content

**Edit**

In fact, a lot of the mimetypes seem off. For instance, on my apache server .pngs are transferred as **image/png** while on the dev server it's **image/x-png**

Comment: Does switching `DEBUG` flag make any difference?

Comment: It's current set to True. Setting it to False doesn't seem to fix the problem (it doesn't seem to allow me to run it without Debug=True)

Comment: Could you check what is the `Content-Type` of the response locally and on the actual site?

Comment: On the local site it's an "application/octet-stream" while on the site it's a "application/json". Weird...

Comment: Could you show your `urls.py` part that configures serving static files?

Comment: Also, could you follow [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/14412233/771848) and check what is the mimetype guessed by the `mimetype` module locally and on the server?

Comment: @alecxe is on it. django uses the python mimetypes module to determine the type. And I believe the mimetypes module itself uses different files in your environment to do the mapping, one of them being common apache files if available. So it's not really a problem with django dev server not being able to set the mimetype correctly, it's basically using what your dev environment provides.

Comment: @toad013 thanks, this is what I was thinking about too.