# python-magic module' object has no attribute 'open'

Tags: python

I am trying to use python-magic package, a wrapper class for libmagic.

I install using "pip install python-magic"
but when I test it:

```
import magic
ms = magic.open(magic.MAGIC_NONE)
ms.load()
```

it shows that module' object has no attribute 'open'. I searched on google and somebody said that one cause is I do not have a __init__.py file. so I checked my peronsal site-packages directory. I found magic.py, magic.pyc, and a folder python_magic-0.4.3-py2.7.egg-info which just include some text files.

How can I get the __init__.py file? I checked other packages installed, some of them do 
have such a file.

Thanks.

Comment: Why do you think it has an `open` function? The source is right here: https://github.com/ahupp/python-magic

Comment: My test code comes from another open source project using magic. I have suspected this before. By dir(magic) I only found magic_load and magic_open, so I replace the above too calls by these two, but it does not work. the return value of magic_open seems to be an int. Do you think the above code assume I am using an older version of python-magic?

Answer (score 7):

There is **no** `magic.open()` function. If you check out the [`python-magic` documentation](https://github.com/ahupp/python-magic/blob/master/README.md) you can see that it has `magic.from_file()` and `magic.from_buffer()` functions.

Use `magic.from_file()` to test against a path name; the module opens that file for you and and determines the type. Use `magic.from_buffer()` to test a byte sequence (`str` in Python 2, `bytes` in Python 3).

There is also a `magic.Magic()` class that you can instantiate (per thread!) to alter how it operates:

```
Magic(mime=False, magic_file=None, mime_encoding=False)
```

documented as:

> Create a new `libmagic` wrapper.
>
> `mime` - if `True`, mimetypes are returned instead of textual descriptions
>   `mime_encoding` - if `True`, codec is returned
>   `magic_file` - use a mime database other than the system default

and according to the `README`, *that is* ***all*** as far as public API is concerned.

The `Magic` class handles `magic.MAGIC_NONE` internally; setting `mime=True` when creating a `magic.Magic()` instance will set a `magic.MAGIC_MIME` flag for example.

It looks as if the code you encountered covers a *different* Python `magic` library altogether that required more internals hand-holding. My advice: Don't try to replicate that. Use this new library and it's documented API **only**.

Comment: Thank you! I also found another helpful post here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43580/how-to-find-the-mime-type-of-a-file-in-python

Comment: Ah, right, so there is a `python-magic` out there that is *not* listed on PyPI and uses a different API.