# How to emulate Firefox "Save File" -> OK in Python

Tags: python, firefox, selenium, web, selenium-webdriver

My following code:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import Select
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By

# Define firefox profile
download_dir = "/Users/pdubois/Desktop/TargetMine_Output/"
fp = webdriver.FirefoxProfile()
fp.set_preference("browser.download.folderList",2)
fp.set_preference("browser.download.manager.showWhenStarting",False)
fp.set_preference("browser.download.dir", download_dir)
#fp.set_preference("browser.helperApps.neverAsk.saveToDisk", "text")
fp.set_preference("browser.helperApps.neverAsk.saveToDisk", "text/plain")


driver = webdriver.Firefox(fp)
driver.implicitly_wait(20)

genes  = "Eif2ak2,Pcgf5,Vps25,Prmt6,Tcerg1,Dnttip2,Preb,Polr1b,Gabpb1,Prdm1,Fosl2,Zfp143,Psip1,Kat6a,Tgif1,Txn1,Irf8,Cnot6l,Zfp451,Foxk2,Lpxn,Etv6,Khsrp,Lmo4,Nkrf,Mafk,Mbd1,Cited2,Elp5,Jdp2,Bzw1,Rbm15b,Klf9,Gtf2e2,Dynll1,Klf6,Stat1,Srrt,Gtf2f1,Adnp2,Ikbkg,Mybbp1a,Nup62,Brd2,Chd1,Kctd1,Sap30,Cebpd,Mtf1,Gtf2h2,Fubp1,Tcea1,Irf2bp2,Ezh2,Hnrpdl,Pml,Cebpz,Med7"
targetmine_url = "http://targetmine.nibio.go.jp/targetmine/begin.do"
driver.get(targetmine_url)

# Define type of list to be submitted
gene_select = Select(driver.find_element_by_name("type"))
gene_select.select_by_visible_text(u"Gene")


# Enter list and submit
gene_input = driver.find_element_by_id("listInput")
gene_input.send_keys(genes)
submit = driver.find_element_by_css_selector("input.button.light").click()

# Choose name for list
driver.find_element_by_id("newBagName").clear()
driver.find_element_by_id("newBagName").send_keys("ADX.06.ID.Clust1")

driver.switch_to_frame("__pomme::0")
# Add All
driver.find_element_by_css_selector("span.small.success.add-all.button").click()
# Save all genes
driver.find_element_by_css_selector("a.success.button.save").click()
# Select M. Musculus
driver.find_element_by_xpath("//ul[@id='customConverter']/li[2]/a[1]").click()

# Gene enrchment part
go_xpath  = "//div[@id='gene_go_enrichment-widget']/div[@class='inner']/div[1]/div[@class='form']/form[@style='margin:0']/div[2]/select[1]"
#driver.find_element_by_xpath(go_xpath).click()
go_select = Select(driver.find_element_by_xpath(go_xpath))
go_select.select_by_visible_text(u"1.00")


# Download 
#driver.find_element_by_css_selector("a.btn.btn-small.export").click()
```

Works fine. Which end with this instances:

[image]

One last thing I want to achieve then is to *Save the file automatically*.
Despite I've already set the Firefox profile at the top
of the code, it doesn't do as I hoped. What's the right way to do it?

**Update:**

The solution by alecxe works.
Except I tried this, it doesn't save the file.

```
go_download_xpath  = "//div[@id='gene_go_enrichment-widget']/div[@class='inner']/div[1]/div[2]/a[@class='btn btn-small export']"

driver.find_element_by_xpath(go_download_xpath).click()
# it saved the specific desired file.
# using 
#driver.find_element_by_css_selector("a.btn.btn-small.export").click()
#save the wrong file.
```

Comment: Ur update...it doesn't save the file...??? Save the wrong file... Pls check that `a.btn.btn-small.export` is unique or not for that element...else it will save click the first one only...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This particular dialog *cannot be controlled via selenium* - this is a browser popup, not a javascript popup (which can be automated with `swith_to.alert`).

In this case, you need to avoid the popup being shown in the first place and make Firefox download the file automatically by tweaking browser's *desired capabilities* (aka profile preferences). Firefox can download files automatically depending on the *mime-type* of the file being downloaded. In your case it is `text/plain`:

```
fp = webdriver.FirefoxProfile()
fp.set_preference("browser.download.folderList",2)
fp.set_preference("browser.download.dir", download_dir)
fp.set_preference("browser.download.manager.showWhenStarting", False)

fp.set_preference("browser.helperApps.neverAsk.saveToDisk", "text/plain")

driver = webdriver.Firefox(firefox_profile=fp)
```

---

FYI, I've downloaded the file manually and used [`magic` module](https://github.com/ahupp/python-magic) to [detect the mime-type](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43580/how-to-find-the-mime-type-of-a-file-in-python):

```
In [1]: import magic

In [2]: mime = magic.Magic(mime=True)

In [3]: mime.from_file("result.tsv")
Out[3]: 'text/plain'
```

Comment: thanks a million. I have minor glitches. Kindly look at my update.

Comment: @pdubois thanks for accepting. Have you solved the latest issue?

Comment: Yes. It's the timing problem. I just add `time.sleep(10)` then it saves.

Comment: @pdubois okay, but think about using [explicit waits](http://selenium-python.readthedocs.org/en/latest/waits.html#explicit-waits) instead of a hardcoded delay with time.sleep.

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```py
fp = webdriver.FirefoxProfile()
fp.set_preference("browser.download.dir", download_dir)
fp.set_preference("browser.preferences.instantApply", True)
fp.set_preference("browser.helperApps.neverAsk.saveToDisk",
                  "text/plain, application/octet-stream, application/binary, text/csv, application/csv, application/excel, text/comma-separated-values, text/xml, application/xml")
fp.set_preference("browser.helperApps.alwaysAsk.force", False)
fp.set_preference("browser.download.manager.showWhenStarting", False)
fp.set_preference("browser.download.folderList", 2)

driver = webdriver.Firefox(firefox_profile=fp)
```