# why is mimetypes.guess_type('a.json') not working in centos 7

Tags: python, python-2.7, mime-types, centos7

In Centos, why is python 2.7 prebuilt library mimetypes.guess_type not returning mimetype for json files?
https://docs.python.org/2/library/mimetypes.html#

I am using guess_type in mimetypes and it returns different value in centos/ubuntu. What's the pythonic way to deduce mimetype from filename in different OS?

In ubuntu 14.04, it returns the correct mime type

```
>>> import mimetypes
>>> mimetypes.guess_type('a.json')
('application/json', None)
```

But in Centos7

```
>>> import mimetypes
>>> mimetypes.guess_type('a.json')
(None, None)
>>> mimetypes.guess_type('a.JSON')
(None, None)
```

I checked the similar question and suggested answer, it will work only if the file of given content exists...
[How to find the mime type of a file in python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43580/how-to-find-the-mime-type-of-a-file-in-python)

Comment: I'm mostly just guessing, but looking at the Python mimetypes code, it looks for files `/etc/mime.types`, `/etc/httpd/conf/mime.types`, etc, and reads those if they exist.  Probably your Ubuntu install has one that maps `.json` while your Centos install doesn't.

Comment: @torek. thanks. installing /etc/mime.types through rpm package(mailcap) solved it.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

On CentOS 7 you will need to install a package named "mailcap":

```
yum search mailcap
```

This is described as "Helper application and MIME type associations for file types".

After installing mailcap, the following will work:

```
>>> import mimetypes
>>> mimetypes.guess_type('a.json')
('application/json', None)
```

Comment: Thanks. There seems to be multiple packages that can give /etc/mime.types in different distro [RPM search](http://rpmfind.net/linux/rpm2html/search.php?query=%2Fetc%2Fmime.types)

Comment: On Debian / Ubuntu: ``apt-get install mime-support``

Answer (score 0):

(A not-so-related answer) On Windows, Mime Types are read from Registry, so you can add mimetypes manually by editing registry entries.

In my case, I developed a python app which receives spread sheets (`.xls` and `.xlsx`). And it worked on my dev computer (Windows 10/11), but on production server (Windows Server 2008), `.xlsx` files are not recognized. `mimetypes.guess_type(someXLSXfile.url)` printed `None`.

So I looked up the registry of server, and it turned out that it was too old that it did not have a `.xlsx` entry. So I added it manually. (Save the code below as `xlsx.reg` and run it on Windows, the entry then can be added.)

```
Windows Registry Editor Version 5.00

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\.xlsx]
@="ET.Xlsx.6"
"Content Type"="application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet"
"PerceivedType"="document"
```

If you happen to know the Content Type that is missing, you can fix it by this way. In the code, you should change `.xlsx` in the square brackets to the extension you want, and for values below, you can copy them from a know computer.