# CSS not loading wrong MIME type Django

Tags: python, css, python-3.x, django, mime-types

I have installed virtualenv in my localhost to run a django app with 1.8 version but when running it the css and js files doesn't load.

I get

```
Resource interpreted as Stylesheet but transferred with MIME type application/x-css
```

I have tried some options but they don't solve the issue either. I am running the same configuration on other PC and it works.

My HTML loads the css with :

```
<link href="/static/css/bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
```

Comment: Possible dublicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22839278/python-built-in-server-not-loading-css

Answer (score 34, accepted):

Adding following snippet into `settings.py` file may fix your problem:

```
import mimetypes
mimetypes.add_type("text/css", ".css", True)
```

Comment: Thanks, that worked ! but why I am having this issue only on some PCs ?

Comment: Because that's related to incorrect association of css file on OS base, after adding lines in answer above all css files should be associated correctly. Also you can take a look on accepted answer of source i've pointed to. Have a nice day )!

Comment: Man, this was driving me crazy.  The app worked fine on my Windows 10 laptop, but did not serve the status assets correctly on my desktop at work. This fixed the problem!!

Comment: This didn't help me at all, I use Windows 7. Running it under virtual environment.

Comment: he path is correct and verified with Pycharm. 
It was placed in settings.pu `import mimetypes
mimetypes.add_type ("text / css", ".css", true)

STATIC_URL = '/ static /'`

But it still doesn't load the link.

Answer (score 24):

This particular behaviour varies between the development (`DEBUG=True`) and deployment environment (`DEBUG=False`).

So if you are developing locally with `DEBUG=False` there is a high chance of this error. But once deployed on any server it will work without any error. If you want to avoid this error during development set `DEBUG=True`.

Comment: How can one avoid this error during production with DEBUG=False?

Comment: I did set up the debug mode on True, but still no success. I have developed [my question there](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75520201/flask-and-css-file-in-pandoc-generated-html). Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 19):

**"whitenoise"** will solve **"MIME type" error** then **CSS** is loaded successfully:

First, install **"whitenoise"**:

```
pip install whitenoise
```

Then,  set it to **"MIDDLEWARE"** in **"settings.py"**. Finally, **CSS** is loaded successfully:

```py
MIDDLEWARE = [
    # ...
    "django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware",
    "whitenoise.middleware.WhiteNoiseMiddleware", # Here
    # ...
]
```

Comment: My problem was in production, trying to host Django app on a shared hosting, whitenoise did the magic.

Comment: This fixed it for me as well on Railway.app

Comment: It worked like a charm, on render.com app. Thank you very much...

Answer (score 12):

I ran into this issue during development (production was using Nginx and serving from /static_cdn folder without any issues).

The solution came from the Django docs: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/howto/static-files/#serving-static-files-during-development

```
from django.conf import settings
from django.conf.urls.static import static

urlpatterns = [
    # ... the rest of your URLconf goes here ...
] + static(settings.STATIC_URL, document_root=settings.STATIC_ROOT)
```

Comment: so this should only be used in development?

Comment: This is a fix for development issues, and should not affect your Prod config

Answer (score 6):

open your Chrome by F12 Developer Tool and check what you actually received. In my case, the CSS file actually redirected to another page. so MIME is `text/html` not `text/css`

Comment: how did you solve for text/html mimetype issue?

Answer (score 2):

Access the CSS file directly. If you get a 404 error that is your answer, because Django serve you a text/html file when the browser expect text/css.

Try to fix your static files, and the problem is most likely solved.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

If you're using Centos and having similar issues (mine were with svgs) then you might need to install the `mailcap` package if it doesn't exist (as per [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33356241/3000741)).

Answer (score 1):

If you happen to be using the [Django whitenoise plugin](http://whitenoise.evans.io/en/stable/), then the `mimetypes` module is not used, and you need to pass in a dictionary of custom types in `settings.py`:

```
WHITENOISE_MIMETYPES = {
    '.xsl': 'application/xml'
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In my case I only loaded

`{% load static %}`

in django and not added the

```
'{%static '<filename>'%}'
```

in hrefs when I added this the error's gone

Answer (score -3):

Set `DEBUG = TRUE`, if you are in dev. You can later in production set it false.