# css issues with html template while running in django server

Tags: html, css, django, django-templates

i have bought a social media template from themforest for my django application 
the html template is perfect without running any server but after integrating and running the server there are some issues with the UI

i have tried checking out all the static files  but everything seems to be good

newsfeed.html

```
    <footer id="footer">

  <div class="container">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="footer-wrapper">
        <div class="col-md-3 col-sm-3">
          <a href=""><img src="{% static 'images/logo-black.png' %}" alt="" class="footer-logo" /></a>
          <ul class="list-inline social-icons">
            <li><a href="#"><i class="icon ion-social-facebook"></i></a></li>
            <li><a href="#"><i class="icon ion-social-twitter"></i></a></li>
            <li><a href="#"><i class="icon ion-social-googleplus"></i></a></li>
            <li><a href="#"><i class="icon ion-social-pinterest"></i></a></li>
            <li><a href="#"><i class="icon ion-social-linkedin"></i></a></li>
          </ul>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-2 col-sm-2">
          <h5>For individuals</h5>
          <ul class="footer-links">
            <li><a href="">Signup</a></li>
            <li><a href="">login</a></li>
            <li><a href="">Explore</a></li>
            <li><a href="">Finder app</a></li>
            <li><a href="">Features</a></li>
            <li><a href="">Language settings</a></li>
          </ul>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-2 col-sm-2">
          <h5>For businesses</h5>
          <ul class="footer-links">
            <li><a href="">Business signup</a></li>
            <li><a href="">Business login</a></li>
            <li><a href="">Benefits</a></li>
            <li><a href="">Resources</a></li>
            <li><a href="">Advertise</a></li>
            <li><a href="">Setup</a></li>
          </ul>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-2 col-sm-2">
          <h5>About</h5>
          <ul class="footer-links">
            <li><a href="">About us</a></li>
            <li><a href="">Contact us</a></li>
            <li><a href="">Privacy Policy</a></li>
            <li><a href="">Terms</a></li>
            <li><a href="">Help</a></li>
          </ul>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-3 col-sm-3">
          <h5>Contact Us</h5>
          <ul class="contact">
            <li><i class="icon ion-ios-telephone-outline"></i>+1 (234) 222 0754</li>
            <li><i class="icon ion-ios-email-outline"></i>info@thunder-team.com</li>
            <li><i class="icon ion-ios-location-outline"></i>228 Park Ave S NY, USA</li>
          </ul>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="copyright">
    <p>Thunder Team © 2016. All rights reserved</p>
  </div>
    </footer>
```

http://mythemestore.com/friend-finder/newsfeed.html this is how it looks without integrating django server

and this is how it looks after integrating  it with django server 
[image]
[image]

i havent added any css code related to this template beacuase the css code is more than 1000 lines 
but if you want  me to add it ,ill just edit and update the question

Comment: send your static file connection on settings.py file

Comment: how am i supposed to do that

Answer (score 0):

Open the chrome developer console and reload the page. Check if you have some kind of error or warning related to css.

I guess this may be the issue.

[css-not-loading-wrong-mime-type-django](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35557129/css-not-loading-wrong-mime-type-django)

Comment: there is no warning related to css

Answer (score 0):

When you are working with a theme you have to include all the required styles in your template. You can see that the styles are missing. Furthermore, do not worry about 1000 lines of css. It is not much after minifying and compression.

Comment: not even a single file is missing  but still the UI is the same