# How do I properly set up a React app using Vite with my Django backend?

Tags: reactjs, django, vite

I've built my Django backend, then created a new app called Frontend. In the frontend folder I started a Vite app called "static" which includes my src folder and other files. When I create a build using npm run build a dist folder is created. I am able to run this project on localhost:5173 but when I want to run on Django (http://127.0.0.1:8000/) I get a blank white screen with errors.

The errors are linked -->

[image: console errors here]

Has anyone gone through this process?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [CSS not loading wrong MIME type Django](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35557129/css-not-loading-wrong-mime-type-django)

Comment: Unfortunately no. I added the mimetypes and whitenoise and still getting the same errors. I realize it could be a number of issues, a little frustrating!

Comment: did you fixed the error?