# Flask and CSS file in pandoc generated HTML

Tags: python, flask, pandoc, pypandoc

I have a Flask application generating and serving static HTML from markdown with pypandoc. Everything goes fine, but the css file is served as `text/html` and not `text/css`, therefore it is not interpretated.

Firefox/Chromium gives the following error :

```
The stylesheet http://127.0.0.1:5000/static/notes.css was not loaded because its MIME type, “text/html”, is not “text/css”.
```

In the Flask app (extract with pypandoc command)

```py
...
    css = url_for('static', filename='notes.css')
    vcss = '--css='+css
    pdoc_args = ['--template=templates/notes.html',
                 vcss
                ]
    output = ppandoc.convert_text(mdblop, 'html', format='markdown', extra_args=pdoc_args, outputfile=filename)
    with open(filename) as fp:
         htmlpage = fp.read()
    return htmlpage
...
```

In the Pandoc template `notes.html`

```html
$for(css)$
<link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="$css$" />
$endfor$
```

I added the `type="text/css"` trying to force the type, but it didn't help/change.

Css file `notes.css` is a standard css file.

In the final HTML served by Flask :

```html
<link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="/static/notes.css" />
```

It seems that Flask does not consider this static file properly as a `text/css` type.

I added the classic function to serve static files, with mimetypes test which interestingly are contradictory:

```py
@app.get("/static/<filename>") 
def route_static(filename):
    filename = os.path.join('static', filename)
    print(mimetypes.guess_type('/static/notes.css')) # returns "('text/css', None)"
    print(mimetypes.read_mime_types('/static/notes.css')) # returns "None" 
    with open(filename) as fp: 
         staticfile = fp.read() 
         return staticfile
```

Comment: Related to [similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35557129/css-not-loading-wrong-mime-type-django), I've also tried with debug mode set to True, but no success in my case.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution looking at the package [flask_FlatPages](https://flask-flatpages.readthedocs.io/en/latest/) (which is not needed in my case, but it documents a way to force the mimetypes of the returned element.

So my function for serving css as `text/css`:

```py
@app.get("/static/notes.css")
def static_notescss():
    filename = os.path.join('static', 'notes.css')
    with open(filename) as fp:
        staticfile = fp.read()
        return staticfile, 200, {'Content-Type': 'text/css'}
```

This final element makes it right : `{'Content-Type': 'text/css'}`