# Why does Django admin render weird?

Tags: python, django, django-admin, django-settings

After hosting my Django project on PythonAnywhere, the Django Admin login page looks like this:
[image]

I have run `python manage.py collectstatic` and this still happens.
There are many errors in the Javascript console that include:

```
Refused to apply style from 'example.com/static/admin/css/dark_mode.css' because its MIME type ('text/html') is not a supported stylesheet MIME type, and strict MIME checking is enabled.
```

The other errors also reference to MIME.
This is my settings.py:

```
STATIC_URL = "/static/"
STATICFILE_DIRS = [BASE_DIR / 'static']
STATIC_ROOT = '/home/mywebsite/surveys/static'
```

I also get these error in the error log:

```
2023-06-22 11:37:29,062: Not Found: /static/admin/css/dark_mode.css
2023-06-22 11:37:29,063: Not Found: /static/admin/css/base.css
2023-06-22 11:37:29,215: Not Found: /static/admin/css/nav_sidebar.css
2023-06-22 11:37:29,224: Not Found: /static/admin/css/login.css
2023-06-22 11:37:29,403: Not Found: /static/admin/css/responsive.css
2023-06-22 11:37:29,404: Not Found: /static/admin/js/nav_sidebar.js
2023-06-22 11:37:29,408: Not Found: /static/admin/js/theme.js
```

Can anyone tell me why this is happening?

Comment: How do you serve these files? Share your webserver configuration for these files.

Comment: I agree with @Macro. The static files in production do not get served by django but by the webserver. Within your webserver's config you have to include the MIME types.

Comment: @Marco sorry for the late reply, i'll get the webserver configurations now

Comment: @Tarquinius Sorry for the late reply, i'll get the webserver configurations now

Comment: refer this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/35557243/19205926

Answer (score 0):

##### You need to add `STATIC_ROOT` instead of `STATICFILES_DIRS`

```
STATIC_URL = '/static/'

STATIC_ROOT = BASE_DIR / 'static'
# STATICFILES_DIRS = [BASE_DIR / 'static'] <---- comment this
```

##### then run the command

- `python manage.py collectstatic`

##### then reload the app (I think it will work)

Answer (score -1):

I fixed the error.
I'm posting this answer for future reference.
I had improperly configured my settings.py for static files.
I needed to change

```
STATIC_URL = "/static/"
STATICFILE_DIRS = [BASE_DIR / 'static']
STATIC_ROOT = '/home/mywebsite/surveys/static'
```

to

```
STATIC_URL = "/static/"
STATICFILE_DIRS = [os.path.join(BASE_DIR, "static"),]
STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'static')
```

And that fixed everything!