# python - How to get mimetypes from file, read metadata

Tags: python, mime-types, file-type

Why do some files not have mimetypes?

`guess_type` returns a *tuple* with information about the *file type*
like  `'image/jpeg'`, `'application/xml'`, `'text/plain'` , `....`

Why do other files return no information `'None'` even though the file exits and is not empty?

```
>> import mimetypes
>> mimetypes.guess_type('myfile.xx')
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

(Answered here: [How to find the mime type of a file in python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43580/how-to-find-the-mime-type-of-a-file-in-python))

---

### **The how**

Do this:

```py
>>> pip install python-magic
>>> import magic
>>> mime = magic.Magic(mime=True)
>>> mime.from_file("testdata/test.pdf")
```

---

### **The why**

The "mimetypes" library isn't very good, (it's unreliable). The "none" is that the specified file isn't recognized as a known filetype, (an extension don't a fileype make).

---

Hope this solves your issue and answers your question

Comment: For me, I first got "raise ImportError('failed to find libmagic.  Check your installation')"  So, it should be noted that you have to first install "libmagic".  I'm on a Mac, so `sudo port install libmagic` took care of that.  However, this solution still incorrectly gave me back "application/octet-stream", when exiftool gave me "MIME Type : video/x-dv", which is correct.  As noted, "mimetypes" also unreliably gave me back "None".

Answer (score 2):

You can install the package with pip install filemime and use it as follows. all type of files find file type and mime type filemime

```
from filemime import filemime

fileObj = filemime()
val = fileObj.load_file("Kodi_Kodi.mp3")
print(f"file: {val}")

mime = fileObj.load_file("Kodi_Kodi.mp3",mimeType=True)
print(f"mime-type: {mime}")
```

output:

```
file: 'Audio file with ID3 version 2.3.0, contains:MPEG ADTS, layer III, v1, 160 kbps, 44.1 kHz, Stereo'
mime-type: 'audio/mpeg'
```