# Downloading .pdf using requests results in corrupted file

Tags: python, beautifulsoup, python-requests

I have a [link](https://www.blackrock.com/uk/individual/literature/annual-report/blackrock-index-selection-fund-en-gb-annual-report-2019.pdf) to a PDF file that I would like to download. I tried the following:

```
import requests

class Scraper:

    def __init__(self):
        """Init the class"""

    @staticmethod
    def download(full_url):
        """Download full url pdf"""
        with requests.Session() as req:

            # Init
            r = req.get(full_url, allow_redirects=True)
            localname = 'test.pdf'

            # Download
            if r.status_code == 200: #and r.headers['Content-Type'] == "application/pdf;charset=UTF-8":
                with open(f"{localname}", 'wb') as f:
                    f.write(r.content)
            else:
                pass
```

However, after downloading, when I try to open it on my computer I receive the message:

> "Could not open [FILENAME].pdf because it is either not a supported
>   file type or because the file has been damaged (...)"

- What is the reason for this? Is it because the first time you visit this page you get redirected and you need to select some preferences?
- How can we resolve this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Actually you haven't passed the `required` parameters for starting the `download`, as if you have navigate to the [url](https://www.blackrock.com/uk/individual/literature/annual-report/blackrock-index-selection-fund-en-gb-annual-report-2019.pdf), you will see that you need to `Click` `continue` in order to start the download. what's happening in the bacground is `GET` request to the back-end with the following `parameters` `?switchLocale=y&siteEntryPassthrough=true` to start the `download`.

You can view that under `developer-tools` within your browser and navigate to the `Network-Tab` section.

```py
import requests


params = {
    'switchLocale': 'y',
    'siteEntryPassthrough': 'true'
}


def main(url, params):
    r = requests.get(url, params=params)
    with open("test.pdf", 'wb') as f:
        f.write(r.content)


main("https://www.blackrock.com/uk/individual/literature/annual-report/blackrock-index-selection-fund-en-gb-annual-report-2019.pdf", params)
```

Comment: Ok, so you need to know these type of params beforehand?

Comment: @JohnAndrews Indeed. that's is `pre-defined` `parameters` by the server side. Unless you implement a `machine learning` model to deal with all cases, such as following `click buttons` or locating the `frame` of `download` words. a long way discussion :P

Comment: Would love to have that discussion someday :)

Comment: @JohnAndrews [sickit-learn](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/) will be your best friend for that tasks

Comment: That is a good reference. But how do you define whether the pdf has actually been downloaded correctly? That would be a good input to your model, to be able to know if it failed or succeeded.

Comment: @JohnAndrews something like `print(r.headers.get("Content-Type"))` or using `magic` for checking [content](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43580/how-to-find-the-mime-type-of-a-file-in-python)