# Linux: Using python, how can I get a list of software that can open a certain file type?

Tags: python

I'm creating a GUI program with python and PyQt5, I want to create an "Open with:" option for it. How do I get a list of all installed software that can run a specific file type? In this case the file type would be image.

[image]

Comment: It would depend on what flavour of Linux you are using and also (probably) on the Desktop Environment you are using - but you should be able to find something in `/usr/share/applications/`. See if this helps - https://askubuntu.com/questions/162612/how-can-i-add-an-application-to-the-list-of-open-with-applications

Answer (score 1):

### The MIME type of the file

Are you able to figure out or specify the mime-type of the file(s) in question?

Besides a more approximate hint like *filename extension* (mostly used on Windows) the MIME type is the association to find a program capable opening the file (and its content).

You could use some Python package to figure out the MIME type of a file, e.g.:

- [How to find the mime type of a file in python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43580/how-to-find-the-mime-type-of-a-file-in-python)

#### Find programs associated with certain MIME types (Linux)

If you are looking for a solution on Linux only, I would recommend:

- [XDG-mime](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/bionic/man1/xdg-mime.1.html)
- https://askubuntu.com/questions/514125/url-protocol-handlers-in-basic-ubuntu-desktop
- https://askubuntu.com/questions/786654/handling-file-open-mime-type-with-python

Or try to collect the MIME related info stored in [**Desktop entry files**](https://specifications.freedesktop.org/desktop-entry-spec/desktop-entry-spec-latest.html) (`.desktop`) commonly in folder `/usr/share/applications/`, as [commented by Mortz](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69280268/linux-using-python-how-can-i-get-a-list-of-software-that-can-open-a-certain-fi/69280588#comment122451389_69280268). As these entries are specified by [Freedesktop.org](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Freedesktop.org) also abbreviated as "XDG" they should be pretty independent from the Linux flavor or desktop-environment.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. It seems like `XDG-mime` is only for either getting the default program for a file type, or for getting the default program for a file. I'm looking for a way to get a list of programs (not just the default) for a file type (not a file). However, I found out about `/etc/mailcap` in another SO post which seems to have exactly what I am looking for; a list of installed programs to run a specific file type.

Answer (score 0):

Going through some other SO posts based on the answers on this post, I happened across the `mailcap` library in python. It was basically what I needed, but not quite. Then finally, though my GUI is made with PyQt5, I could get what I wanted with `Gio` from PyGtk. Code to get it:

```py
import gi
gi.require_version('Gtk', '3.0')
from gi.repository import Gio

print(Gio.app_info_get_all_for_type('image/png'))
```