# How does Amazon S3 recognize file types？

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, boto3, mime-types

When I manually add files to Amazon S3 , it automatically identifies the file type as follows,

[image]

Is there any way I can use AWS SDK boto3 to identify file types? There seems to be no such interface.

I already know about python mimetypes module, but it doesn't work to my liking.

Comment: of course you can use boto (`get_object(...)['ContentType']`) for existing objects. for new objects, you should know (or guess) the content type....

Comment: for "guessing", i'd recommend: https://stackoverflow.com/q/43580/592355

Answer (score 1):

It's about the object metadata sent along the request. When uploading an object manually, the console sets the content-type header for recognized extensions (I'm not sure where is the list).

When using the AWS SDK, you may provide the `Content-Type` parameter along the [put_object](https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/reference/services/s3.html#S3.Client.put_object) operation