# Get mime types of all files in a folder with Python

Tags: python, mime-types

I have a folder of files with no extension that range from mp4 to png i need to sort them base on mime type to give them the right extension but i can't find any way of geting mime type of more than 1 file. I need to get of all the files in that folder.

I tried using built in lib `mimetypes`  with an array but i got `TypeError: expected str, bytes or os.PathLike object, not list`.

**Edit**:
Comment by [Jay](https://stackoverflow.com/users/8677071/jay) solved my issue.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to find the mime type of a file in python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43580/how-to-find-the-mime-type-of-a-file-in-python)

Comment: You will have to loop over all the files in the dir one by one.