# Download and save file without knowing its extension

Tags: python, python-requests

I'm quite new to Python. I need to write a script that downloads several assets and saves them to a directory. I've got a JSON file where the URL for each asset is specified.

```json
{
  "asset1": "SOME_URL/ASSET_NAME.png",
  "asset2": "SOME_URL/ASSET_NAME.pdf",
  "asset3": "SOME_URL/ASSET_NAME.jpeg"
}
```

Since I don't know the extension beforehand, I'm currently unsure how to save the assets to a directory.
I would also like to specify the file name beforehand and not use the one of the remote file.

I was trying to do it as follows but this is obviously not the way to go.

```py
from urllib.request import urlretrieve

for url in [asset_url_1, asset_url_2, asset_url_3]:
  # I would like to already specify the name of the asset
  # What's the extension?
  output_path = "tmp/output/WHAT_TO_PUT_HERE?"
  urlretrieve(url, output_path)
```

Comment: Actually you know the extension from the JSON...

Comment: Also check [How to find the mime type of a file in python?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/43580/4046632)

Comment: So what do you want, exactly?  How these file should be downloaded as?

Answer (score 0):

I usually us `os` python package to handle fht file system

```
import os
from urllib.request import urlretrieve
import json

# Load JSON containing your file information
with open('your_json_file.json') as f:
    asset_urls = json.load(f)

# output directory
output_directory = 'tmp/output'

for asset_name, url in asset_urls.items():
    
    file_extension = url.split('.')[-1] # Extract only file extension
    local_name = f"{asset_name}.{file_extension}" # local file name
    output_path = os.path.join(output_directory, local_name) # Construct the full output path
    urlretrieve(url, output_path) # Download 
    print(f"Downloaded {asset_name} to {output_path}")
```

Answer (score -1):

You can use pathlib to do what you are asking:

```
import pathlib

out_dir = pathlib.Path("/some/path/to/save")
asset = pathlib.Path("http://www.someurl.com/asset.json")
out_path = out_dir / asset.with_stem("new_stem").name
```

Comment: That's not robust as `Path` may use something different then `/` as path separator.

Comment: @BlackJack the '/' operator is just an override of the division operator to insert a path separator. If you're on Windows the correct path separator gets inserted.

Comment: I'm not talking about the `/` operator in Python but that this code assumes that you can use a URL as `Path` as if `/` is always a valid path separator for `Path` objects.

Comment: I honestly don't know why my solution is getting downvoted. It solves the exact problem the question asked. If the data the poster is working with looks like what he posted, then my solution is simple and works.

Comment: No it doesn't really. Only if you assume that `/` is a path separator. Always and everywhere.  Wrapping a URL in a `Path` object is wrong. It's a hack, not a clean, robust solution.  URLs are not file system paths.